# punctuation from times

Tags: fonts, pdftex

i'm using pdflatex and my math font is palatino. i want to change the punctutation into times because apostrophe is so similar derivation symbol. i used the command below but it changed all math into times. what command should i use?

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{T1}{ptm}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{;}{\mathpunct}{letters}{59}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{letters}{44}}
```

an axample

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}  


\begin{document}
$x'$'
\end{document}
```

second should come from times...

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want to change the *text* or *math* punctuation?

Comment: i want to change math punctuation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define a new symbol font, not overwrite one already existing:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{timespunct}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{timespunct}{bold}{T1}{ptm}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{;}{\mathpunct}{timespunct}{59}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{timespunct}{44}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareSymbolFont{timespunct}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{timespunct}{bold}{T1}{ptm}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{;}{\mathpunct}{timespunct}{59}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{timespunct}{44}

\begin{document}
$a,b;c$
\end{document}
```

### Original (with only `mathpazo`)

[image]

### With the added code

[image]

### Comment

I'm not sure to understand why you'd want this. A comma in math would be printed much differently than a comma in text, making the document unbalanced.

Comment: in my language sometimes we use derivation symbol (ctrl 2) and apostrophe consecutively. so they should seem all different.

Comment: also i need to change apostrophe symbol. if possible i want some greek letters form times. i hope it's not too much:) thanks.

Comment: @mert The prime symbol with `mathpazo` is very different from the apostrophe. Changing the *text* apostrophe is a much different job.